# How do I add last modified in the footer of my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add the date and time the web page was last updated.

Here is the JavaScript code. I don't see why this does not work.

```
var lastModified = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("modified").innerHTMLl() = lastModified;
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Use the right syntax for `.innerHTML =`

Comment: @blex Thanks. I'm new to JS. But this still doesn't work.

Comment: Then, it could be related to other parts of your code. You're sure you have an element with an `id="modified"` on your page? Does your code run **after** the element exists on the page? Try putting your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag. Otherwise, open your browser console (F12, `Console` tab) and check if any errors are displayed. If not, go into the `Network` tab, reload, find your HTML page, and check the response headers to see if they contain the `last-modified` header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Syntax error

As already given in the comments, there is a syntax error in the second line of the script. It should be as follows:

```
var lastModified = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("modified").innerHTML = lastModified;
```

(note the removed `l()`).

## Viability of this approach

Note that while it does for a basic "last modified" display, in today's web, there are a lot of factors to consider when defining "last modified". Your approach will basically just display what the server told about the modification time in the respective HTTP header.

Consider an upload to a remote fileserver which is served to your users: Will it display the actual changed date or just the date of the upload (depends on whether the upload sets the modification time for the file as it writes it, so you'd better try out)? Is the page generated in some way? (In this case, it could very well display the time of generation instead of the actual changes).

Comment: It is just a static web page. But I need the time to update every time I modify the file and save it.

Comment: Again, it very much depends on what the server makes of your file: Does it process the last modified information? Does it know about the correct date of last modification. E.g. in case the server always receives the file right after you updated it, the date displayed by your method may be acceptably accurate. But in case the server gets the updated files more rarely (or not incrementally) the date might be incorrect. The easiest way to find out is really to test it thoroughly :)